# UWP doesn't use best scaled Splash Screen

Tags: image, uwp, scale, assets, splash-screen

I have all necessary scales in my project:

[image: Scaled Splash Screens]

However, when I start my app, it doesn't seem to pick the best scaled Splash Screen. I'm starting in Release x86. It's always using the scale-100 splashscreen.

[image: Wrong Splash Screen]

I used the right names for the SplashScreens and they are in the folder "Assets" in my project:

[image: Names of the assets]

Do I have to 'activate' an option to enable the usage of variable Splash Screens? Or why does it always pick a Splash Screen that's too small?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason Windows is using the scale-100 asset in your case is because your desktop environment is set to 100% scaling. There's no need for it to use a higher-resolution asset because of this. But that's not the reason why your asset isn't stretching to fill the window.

Splash screens in Windows Store apps (including UWP apps) are unlike most conventional splash screens in that their images aren't full screen images. Usually, what you put in a splash screen image for a UWP app is the app icon or logo, which is then centered on the variable-sized window and superimposed over an optional background color, rather than itself stretched (since windows can be of arbitrary size, whereas your splash screen image may require a specific aspect ratio to display correctly). From [Guidelines for splash screens](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465338.aspx):

> Putting an image and background color together to form the splash screen helps the splash screen look good regardless of the form factor of the device your app is installed on. When the splash screen is displayed, only the size of the background changes to compensate for a variety of screen sizes. Your image always remains intact.

Comment: That sounds legit. The only problem I have with this is that as you can see in screenshot 1, I have to set SplashScreens which have a resolution for a full size window. I can't set my logo (which is in "Store Logo") in the "Splash Screen" section.

Answer (score 4):

If you really need to display a full-screen image instead of the small splash screen, you can fully omit these images and use an [extended splash screen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-a-customized-splash-screen).

Comment: This link suggest for the extended splash screen `Your extended splash screen page should use a 620 x 300 pixel image that is consistent with the image specified for your splash screen in your app manifest `. That sounds to me like if you would provide a full-screen image there, the app would first display the slash screen with the logo in the center and mono-colored background and then display the full-screen images. Those two slash screens sound together. Are you saying that it behaves differently?